# Struts2 rest request asking for execute method

Tags: rest, struts2

I am new to struts. I am writing a web application using struts2 rest. I have struts2 configured to accept both rest and non rest url. ( following http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/rest-plugin.html)

I expect "http://mylocalhost.com/myApp/detail" url to call DetailController class's index() method. However, I got this error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.project.struts.rest.controllers.DetailController.execute()
    java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1665)
```

It seems struts worked out it need to call detailController, but it tries to call the execute() method instead of the index() method.

Have I missed something in my struts config?

```
struts.xml configure file:
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
           "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
           "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
        <struts>
        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
        <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="xhtml,,xml,json,action"/>
        <constant name="struts.mapper.class" value="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.PrefixBasedActionMapper" />
        <constant name="struts.mapper.prefixMapping" value="/rest:rest,:struts"/>
        <constant name="struts.convention.action.suffix" value="Controller"/>
        <constant name="struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches" value="true"/>
        <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="rest-default"/>
        <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="controllers"/>
</struts>
```

I have a controller called DetailController in com.project.struts.rest.controllers

DetailController class:
    package com.project.struts.rest.controllers;

```
import org.apache.struts2.rest.DefaultHttpHeaders;
import org.apache.struts2.rest.HttpHeaders;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;

public class DetailController implements ModelDriven<Object> {

    private String propertyId;

    @Override
    public Object getModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    // GET /test/1
    public HttpHeaders show() {
        return new DefaultHttpHeaders("show");
    }

    // GET /test
    public HttpHeaders index() {
        return new DefaultHttpHeaders("index");
    }

}
```

Comment: it will call execute, so you have to provide it in your action class.

Comment: How to I make it call index() instead? I thought http://mylocalhost.com/myApp/detail URL is a restful url which should map to detailCollection's index() method.

Comment: What Struts version do you use? And how did you distinguish rest from non-rest requests?

Comment: I created the complete example for Struts2 with REST and Non-REST together, https://github.com/sivailango/struts2-rest-nonrest